# Visual Basic Friend Error

Tags: vb.net

Im having trouble working out making a converter for mutliple currencys using multiple subs. I keep receiving an error saying that number is a friend , and therefore cannot be used in the jap conversion . can anyone help ? thank you in advance

```
Option Explicit On
'Option Strict On

Imports System

Module Yahtzed

    Sub CANtoUSD()
        Dim Number , USDConversion as Decimal
        Number = Console.Readline
        USDConversion =( Number * 1.0141)
        Console.Writeline(USDConversion)
    End Sub

    Sub CANtoJAP()
        Dim Number, JAPConversion as Decimal
        Number = Console.Readline
        JAPConversion =( Number * 79.9392)
        Console.Writeline(JAPConversion)
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Console.Writeline("Enter the CAN amount: ")
        CANtoUSD()
        CANtoJAP()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Post the **exact** error message.  And the **exact** code that produces that error.

Comment: BC30389: 'system.number' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend', and that is the exact code. thank you for your reply

Comment: There's a "Dim Number" missing in the code you compile.  The space after the first "Number" is strange.   Retype the code, use "Value" instead of "Number".

Comment: Note: You should put the `Option Strict` back in - then fix any errors - this will help you in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Not a direct answer, but this requires more space than would work in a comment.*</sup>

You have a fundamental design error in your code. You really want to structure it more like this:

```
Function CANtoUSD(Number As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim USDConversion as Decimal = 1.0141
    Return USDConversion * Number
End Function 

Function CANtoJAP(Number As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim JAPConversion as Decimal = 79.9392
    Return JAPConversion * Number
End Function 

Sub Main()
    Console.Writeline("Enter the CAN amount: ")
    Dim input As Decimal = Console.ReadLine()

    Console.WriteLine(CANtoUSD(input))
    Console.WriteLine(CANtoJAP(input))
End Sub
```

You don't want to mix responsibilities for you methods. The input/output should be strictly separated from the code that manipulates the data. If nothing else, this makes it easier to test that your specific conversion methods work exactly like they are supposed to, and could not be the source of your bug.

Later on, you'll learn how to also ahave a single method that accepts a key value for both source and destination types, and does a table lookup to convert any currency to any other by knowing the conversion factor to a common currency.

Comment: Thank you Joel! That helped so much!