# Making Change In vb

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Basic Friend Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925558/visual-basic-friend-error)

I am trying to create a program to make change using a different sub. So far, im just working on the dollar and quarter , but im having some major problems. Can anyone help ? thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit On
'Option Strict On

Imports System

Module Conversion
  Sub Coin()
    Number = (Number mod 1.00)
    Console.Writeline(Number)
    Number = (Number mod 0.25)
    Console.Writeline(Number)
  End Sub

  Sub Main()
    Console.Write("Enter the Canadian dollar amount: ")
    Dim input As Decimal = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim Number As Decimal = Input
    Coin()
  End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Define "major problems".  What exactly is the problem, where are you getting stuck, what errors are you getting, etc.?

Comment: You have a major problem describing what your major problem is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Coin` can't see `Number`. You must pass `Number` as an argument to `Coin()` like this:

```
Sub Main()
  Console.Write("Enter the Canadian dollar amount: ")
  Dim input As Decimal = Console.ReadLine()
  Dim Number As Decimal = Input
  Coin(Number)
End Sub

Sub Coin(Number as Decimal)
  Number = (Number mod 1.00)
  Console.Writeline(Number)
  Number = (Number mod 0.25)
  Console.Writeline(Number)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Number` is undefined in the `Coin()` method. You have to either make `Coin()` take a parameter or make `Number` a member of your module accessible to `Coin()`

For example:

```
Sub Coin(Byval Number as Decimal)
  Number = (Number mod 1.00)
  Console.Writeline(Number)
  Number = (Number mod 0.25)
  Console.Writeline(Number)
End Sub
```